# How to increase Ubuntu partition on AWS?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, amazon-ec2

Once I got AWS EC2 instance, it had 8Gb drive. I expanded it in control panel from 8Gb to 16Gb and I was not required to do anything else: once I restarted instance, I got 16Gb drive. Next I have expanded drive from 16Gb to 60Gb and this time this was not reflected in the running system.

Why? And how to increase a filesystem then?

**UPDATE**

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            31428656        0  31428656   0% /dev
tmpfs            6288016     9136   6278880   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      16197524 16181140         0 100% /
tmpfs           31440072        0  31440072   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           31440072        0  31440072   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            6288016        0   6288016   0% /run/user/1000
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have performed everything described here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html#return-expanded-root-partition

but still have the same report from `df`.

I don't see any actions to increase filesystem, only partition.

I have Ok partition:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  60G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  60G  0 part /
```

Comment: Gb = Gigabit, GB = Gigabyte. Which one do u mean?

Comment: Gigabyte, but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the only thing I was to do, is to issue a command

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```

It worked on mounted root partition. Now I am not sure if my steps of detaching and attaching volume to secondary instance were required....